# How can I select all rows where every column doesn't match a value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select a value itself that is not equals some statement.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE * != "qwerty"
```

But not like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name != "qwerty"
```

How can I do that?

I have a table like

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   ...   ...
    1  a   b   c   d   t   h   v   h   d   t    y    ...   ...
    2  g   t   5   s   h   r   q   q   q   q    q    ...   ...
   ... ...
   ... ...
```

I need to select every value that is not equals "q"

I could do smth like

```
SELECT * WHERE 1 != q AND 2 != q AND 3 != q ...
```

but I have toomany columns

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample data, table structure and expected output.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question title based on my understanding of what you want, feel free to undo my edit if I was wrong.

Comment: Can you use PHP (or whatever you prefer) or does this need to be in pure MySQL?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "qwerty" NOT IN (column1,column2,column3,column4,etc)
```

Another example:

```
-- this...
SELECT 'HELLO!' FROM tblx 
WHERE 'JOHN' NOT IN (col1,col2,col3);

-- ...is semantically equivalent to:
SELECT 'HELLO!' FROM tblx 
WHERE 'JOHN' <> col1
  AND 'JOHN' <> col2
  AND 'JOHN' <> col3;
```

Data source:

```
create table tblx(col1 text,col2 text,col3 text);
 insert into tblx values
('GEORGE','PAUL','RINGO'), 
('GEORGE','JOHN','RINGO');
```

---

If you are using Postgresql, you can make a shortcut for columns:

```
select * 
from
(
select 

   row(tblx.*)::text AS colsAsText,

   translate(row(tblx.*)::text,'()','{}')::text[]
      as colsAsArray

from tblx
) x
where 'JOHN' <> ALL(colsAsArray)
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8de35/2

Postgres can make rows from arrays, `'JOHN' <> ALL` is equivalent to::

```
where 'JOHN' NOT IN (SELECT unnest(colsAsArray))
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8de35/6

---

If the above is really what you wanted to achieve, searching is much better if you use full-text search

- Postgresql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch.html
- Sql Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx
- MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

---

---

For MySQL:

```
select 
  @columns := group_concat(column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'tblx'
group by table_name;




set @dynStmt := 
   concat('select * from tblx where ? NOT IN (',  @columns ,')');



select @dynStmt;

prepare stmt from @dynStmt;

set @filter := 'JOHN';

execute stmt using @filter;

deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8de35/49

Comment: A quick trip to sqlfiddle shall verify that that is AND http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6741e/2

Comment: Oh yeah, NOT OR is actually and AND LOL (+1)

Comment: @MichaelBuen I think he wanted a way to write the sql statement without specifying the column names! Is that even possible?

Comment: @Songo Yeah, but not that many RDBMS copy Postgres capabilities

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the where expression you want.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' != ''q'' AND ') as Exp
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```

Perhaps you can use this in some dynamic SQL or copy and past the string to your real query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM SomeTable
```

This will return all the columns info.

example:

```
    [Field] => id
    [Type] => int(7)
    [Null] =>  
    [Key] => PRI
    [Default] =>
    [Extra] => auto_increment
```

You can then use **Michael Buen**'s answer to get the values you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "qwerty" NOT IN (columnName1,columnName2,columnName3,columnName4,etc)
```